# Same background image for all view controllers in Swift

Tags: swift, image, background

I would like to set the same background image for all of the view controllers. Here is what I've tried:

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg_name.png")
backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
```

But that only works by copy-pasting it everywhere. What's a better way to do this?

Comment: I would like to set a background image for all the view controllers by using Swift.

Comment: So if you **know** how do to it *per* VC... what's the issue? Certainly *not* "how to do it". Obviously - in that case, and you haven't said anything to say it isn't - a simple subclass does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you would like to have the same background image in all view controllers then one option would be to create a custom base `ViewController` class and have all your other classes inherit from that. For example -

```
class BackgroundImageViewController: ViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad(_animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad(animated: animated)
    let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg_name.png")
    backgroundImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
  }

}
```

And then -

```
class AnotherViewController: BackgroundImageViewController {

  // Your normal view controller stuff

}
```

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for addressing how the concept of *subclassing* - very much a base concept - answers what has (so far) been asked.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an extension of the view controller class

```
extension UIViewController {

    /// This function sets an image as the background of the view controller
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - imageName: name of image
    ///   - contentMode:
    ///          .scaleAspectFill
    ///          .scaleAspectFit
    ///          .scaleToFill
    func setBackgroundImage(_ imageName: String, contentMode: UIViewContentMode) {
        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        backgroundImage.contentMode = contentMode
        self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
    }

}
```

Usage in any UIViewController class

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setBackgroundImage("name_image", contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)
}
```